# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereRequest, but class was expected

Tags: jsf, primefaces, push, atmosphere

In attempt to run PrimeFaces push on GlassFish Server 4.1, I get the following exception, when the following JAR files from [`atmosphere-runtime-libs-2.4.0-RC6-distribution`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Catmosphere%20libs) zip are added to the class-path.

I added the following JAR files from the distribution zip bundle.

- atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0-RC6.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar

<sub>Alternatively tried using `atmosphere-jersey-libs-2.4.0-RC6-distribution.zip` but to no avail.</sub>

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[Push Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Push Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereRequest, but class was expected
    at org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointMapper.computePath(PushEndpointMapper.java:54)
    at org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointMapper.map(PushEndpointMapper.java:78)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.map(AsynchronousProcessor.java:381)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:179)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:109)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.service(Servlet30CometSupport.java:68)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:2310)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doPost(AtmosphereServlet.java:190)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doGet(AtmosphereServlet.java:176)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The following Servlet is registered in `web.xml`.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/websockets/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The application is deployed successfully. The exception occurs at run-time i.e. when the web page in question is requested.

[PrimeFaces 5.2 user guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation) states the following Maven dependency (I do not use Apache Maven to build and deploy the application maintaining libraries loosely / manually).

> Atmosphere is required to run PrimeFaces Push, in your `pom.xml`
>   define the dependency as;
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
>     <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
>     <version>2.3.RC6 or newer</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

Accordingly, it should function with `2.4.0-RC6`.

What is the problem? It should be compatible according to the user guide. Does it require some other libraries for [`<p:socket>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/notify.xhtml) to work?

---

Using Mojarra 2.2.12 / PrimeFaces 5.2 (community release) on GlassFish Server 4.1.

---

**Update :**

When the following libraries are attempted,

- atmosphere-runtime-2.3.0-RC6.jar
- slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
- slf4j-jdk14-1.6.1.jar

the web page is left blank and the server logs the following message, when the page is requested.

```
Info:   Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Atmosphere LifeCycle with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Info:   Installed AtmosphereInterceptor  Track Message Size Interceptor using | with priority BEFORE_DEFAULT 
Info:   Atmosphere is using org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor for processing annotation
Info:   AnnotationProcessor class org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor$ServletContainerInitializerAnnotationProcessor being used
Info:   Found Annotation in class org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointProcessor being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.AtmosphereAnnotation
Info:   Found Annotation in class org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointInterceptor being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.service.AtmosphereInterceptorService
Info:   Found Annotation in class org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointMapper being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.service.EndpointMapperService
Info:   Found Annotation in class primefaces.push.Push being scanned: interface org.primefaces.push.annotation.PushEndpoint
Info:   Installed AtmosphereHandler org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointHandlerProxy mapped to context-path /notify and Broadcaster Class org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster
Info:   Installed AtmosphereInterceptor [@PushEndpoint Interceptor] mapped to AtmosphereHandler org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointHandlerProxy
Info:   Auto detecting WebSocketHandler in /WEB-INF/classes/
Info:   Installed WebSocketProtocol org.atmosphere.websocket.protocol.SimpleHttpProtocol 
Info:   Installing Default AtmosphereInterceptors
Info:       org.atmosphere.interceptor.CorsInterceptor : CORS Interceptor Support
Info:       org.atmosphere.interceptor.CacheHeadersInterceptor : Default Response's Headers Interceptor
Info:       org.atmosphere.interceptor.PaddingAtmosphereInterceptor : Browser Padding Interceptor Support
Info:       org.atmosphere.interceptor.AndroidAtmosphereInterceptor : Android Interceptor Support
Info:       org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor : Heartbeat Interceptor Support
Info:       org.atmosphere.interceptor.SSEAtmosphereInterceptor : SSE Interceptor Support
Info:       org.atmosphere.interceptor.JSONPAtmosphereInterceptor : JSONP Interceptor Support
Info:       org.atmosphere.interceptor.JavaScriptProtocol : Atmosphere JavaScript Protocol
Info:       org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor
Info:       org.atmosphere.interceptor.OnDisconnectInterceptor : Browser disconnection detection
Info:       org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor
Info:   Set org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptor.disableDefaults to disable them.
Info:   Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Atmosphere LifeCycle with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Info:   Installed AtmosphereInterceptor  Track Message Size Interceptor using | with priority BEFORE_DEFAULT 
Info:   Installed AtmosphereInterceptor CORS Interceptor Support with priority FIRST_BEFORE_DEFAULT 
Info:   Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Default Response's Headers Interceptor with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Info:   Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Browser Padding Interceptor Support with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Info:   Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Android Interceptor Support with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Info:   HeartbeatInterceptor configured with padding value 'X', client frequency 60 seconds and server frequency 0 seconds
Info:   Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Heartbeat Interceptor Support with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Info:   Installed AtmosphereInterceptor SSE Interceptor Support with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Info:   Installed AtmosphereInterceptor JSONP Interceptor Support with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Info:   Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Atmosphere JavaScript Protocol with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Info:   Installed AtmosphereInterceptor org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Info:   Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Browser disconnection detection with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Info:   Installed AtmosphereInterceptor org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor with priority BEFORE_DEFAULT 
Info:   Using EndpointMapper class org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointMapper
Warning:   No BroadcasterCache configured. Broadcasted message between client reconnection will be LOST. It is recommended to configure the org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache
Info:   Default Broadcaster Class: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster
Info:   Broadcaster Shared List Resources: false
Info:   Broadcaster Polling Wait Time 100
Info:   Shared ExecutorService supported: true
Info:   Messaging Thread Pool Size: Unlimited
Info:   Async I/O Thread Pool Size: 200
Info:   Using BroadcasterFactory: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcasterFactory
Info:   Using AtmosphereResurceFactory: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAtmosphereResourceFactory
Info:   Using WebSocketProcessor: org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor
Info:   Invoke AtmosphereInterceptor on WebSocket message true
Info:   HttpSession supported: false
Info:   Atmosphere is using org.atmosphere.inject.InjectableObjectFactory for dependency injection and object creation
Info:   Atmosphere is using async support: org.atmosphere.container.GlassFishServ30WebSocketSupport running under container: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  with WebSocket enabled.
Info:   Atmosphere Framework 2.3.0-RC6 started.
Info:   
    For Atmosphere Framework Commercial Support, visit 
    http://www.async-io.org/ or send an email to support@async-io.org

Info:   Installed AtmosphereInterceptor @PushEndpoint Interceptor with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Info:   Latest version of Atmosphere's JavaScript Client 2.2.12
Info:   
    Current version of Atmosphere 2.3.0-RC6 
    Newest version of Atmosphere available 2.2.8
```

---

**Update 2 :**

The same thing happens using PrimeFaces 5.3 final (community release).

Comment: I'd try to stick with the 2.3.x releases first. There most likely was no 2.4.x when the 5.2 docs were writen, so expecting that to work is not always correct

Comment: I tried using `atmosphere-runtime-2.3.0-RC1` and `atmosphere-runtime-2.3.5` with `slf4j-api-1.6.1`. None of them worked. They issue other warnings / errors.

Comment: I don't see any errors here, or do I miss something? What does the browser console show

Comment: Warnings/errors have gone once `slf4j-jdk14-1.6.1.jar` is added in addition to those two libraries but it does not function. Trying to run the [showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/notify.xhtml) without any modification. The web page is left blank (white). XHR headers in the traffic monitor indicate, "200 OK". Perhaps, it has to do something with the target server. It may require some additional configurations.

Comment: Then I'd focus on that…  getting it to work in general on GlassFish. For me it works great on wildfly…  might indeed be a more generic issue with atmosphere and glassfish

Comment: The same thing happens on Apache Tomcat 8.0.9.0 leaving the same log message.